# XmlHttp Sometimes Flips # to %23 in the url string

Tags: xml, vb6, httprequest, msxml6

I have a bit of a dilemma that I really could use some help with please. You see I need to copy the data from a web page into a worksheet and am having some dilemma with the following code block using XML 6.0

```
Dim httpRequest As XMLHTTP

Set httpRequest = New XMLHTTP
httpRequest.Open "GET", URL, False
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
httpRequest.send ""
```

At this point I have a Data Object to catch the data. 99 out of 100 times everything works great. Unfortunately this particular URL string has a "#" in it and it keeps getting converted to "%23" so I keep getting the wonderful error 404. The # MUST be in the URL. There is no other address or way to get to it than to include the #.

Example:

```
http://www.thisaddress.com/MovingFoward/#/Facility94
```

converts to and tries to pull from

```
http://www.thisaddress.com/MovingFoward/%23/Facility94
```

How does one go about preventing any kind of string character conversion?

Comment: How do you create the `URL`?

Comment: Is this some type of weird API? - The `#` in a URL is a Fragment; it only has meaning for an interactive browser - its not even sent to a web server in a regular GET/POST so its hard to see why the output would differ if its missing

Comment: You are right sir. It is part of an interactive page and real time updated. It doesn't matter where the # is. If it's part of a word it still gets converted. You could have something like "This#Phrase" and it will come out "This%23Phrase". @AlexK.

When you click through options the address bar reflects the options you choose but still contains the #. Example:
`http://www.thisaddress.com/MovingFoward/#/Facility94/LeftOver/Z/Down`
If one manually pastes to the browser it works and navigates to the exact option. The URL variable is passing the string correctly. I wonder if it's in setRequestHead

Comment: John - The URL isn't created by anything fancy. I'd like to in the future but for now it's just a simple, normal one piece string without any extra dynamics/variables to it. @JohnSaunders

Comment: In that case,  I don't believe it. Even in VB6, strings don't magically change. There's something else going on. For instance, maybe the server is redirecting sometimes to the bad URL.

Comment: Xmlhttp is not a browser so if the page uses JavaScript to do anything based on the hash you will need a different approach